# Unfortunately Stops in Google Maps api v2

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to implement Google Maps api v2 in my application.

I am following the documentation of Google over here [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

But all times my app crashes Unfortunately,without showing me the map.

Then i followed this tutorial for implementing Google Maps [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/)

But my problem remains unchanged.
please some one advice me how can i solve my problem.
I have attached my Error Log here.[image]

**Edit**

activity_main.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <fragment 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
       android:id="@+id/myMap"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest.xml

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.see_google_maps_demo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permissions.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.see_google_maps_demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <permission android:name="com.example.see_google_maps_demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
                android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:debuggable="true" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.see_google_maps_demo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="my key v2"/>
        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="4.1.32" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap gm;
    LatLng fromPosition = new LatLng(13.687140112679154, 100.53525868803263);
    LatLng toPosition = new LatLng(13.683660045847258, 100.53900808095932);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gm = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.myMap)).getMap();

        LatLng coordinates = new LatLng(13.685400079263206, 100.537133384495975);
        gm.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinates, 13));

        gm.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("FROM").position(fromPosition));
        gm.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("To").position(toPosition));
    }



}
```

**Edit:-**
my error log
[link](http://pastie.org/8721198)

Comment: post the releavant xml layout and the manifest and the activity code

Comment: check `XML` file, you will find the error.:)

Comment: google map v2 will not show on emulator.for that u need a real device!!

Comment: @sanjay
ya..i had checked it in real device too

Comment: @JayVyas change your `android:targetSdkVersion="16"` and try

Comment: @JayVyas also add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />` in your `manifest.xml`

Comment: have a look on this post:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668496/google-maps-v2-simple-application-not-working

Answer (score 1):

add in xml fragment

```
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

also in

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="4.1.32" />
```

try it for value="4132500"

Answer (score 0):

If your xml file is like this,

```
 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

In class file instead of fragment activity use, SupportFragmentActivity

Comment: I don't think this makes any difference. Fragment Activity should work since its the base class for SUpport fragments

Comment: pls check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162983/activity-layout-fragment-class-vs-androidname-attributes

Answer (score 0):

Xml:-

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.see_google_maps_demo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.see_google_maps_demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.see_google_maps_demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mapdemo.ActivityMain"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="YOUR KEY" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Why you changed `android:minSdkVersion="13"` instead of `android:minSdkVersion="8"`??

Comment: see the updated answer.
And Write class instead of android:name in your xml

Comment: @user3243147 that make no difference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162983/activity-layout-fragment-class-vs-androidname-attributes